# Sum Formula with tan90

Tags: trigonometry

I haven't seen any article that says not to apply the total-difference formulas in tan90 anywhere.

But if ı have tan135 and ı want to show it with total difference formula, Can't ı do it like this.

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoUSt.jpg)

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $\tan 90^{\circ}$ is infinite so it's hard to manipulate the formula as you have done.

Comment: Congratulations! (I mean this sincerely.) Even though no one has told you not to use the formula in that way, you have shown for yourself that doing so is a bad idea. :) Infinite and/or undefined values are tricky. Calculus (and, especially, Analysis) courses are traditionally where the nuances start to receive serious attention.

Comment: @lulu undefined would be a better description than infinite.

Comment: There's a grand old tradition of "fake proofs" that purport to show things such as $0=1$ or $1=2,$ sometimes by humorously misquoting methods of proof but very often by disguising undefined operations such as $0/0$ or $\infty - \infty.$ Your proof is one of the latter kind, and it's one I have not seen before, so I think it's pretty creative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things like the angle-sum formulae have built-in conditions, that mean that they're only true in the domain where everything is well-defined. So the formula

$$\tan(x+y) = \frac{\tan(x) + \tan(y)}{1 - \tan(x)\tan(y)}$$

only works if $\tan(x), \tan(y), \tan(x+y)$ all exist. When $x = 90^\circ$, $\tan(x)$ is undefined, and so the angle-sum formula breaks down.

The last few lines of your calculations are essentially writing $??? - ??? = -2$, where $???$ doesn't represent a meaningful value. It's like writing $\infty - \infty$, which doesn't make sense as an arithmetic operation.